# Using bootstrap-switch in a form with ui:repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that will display a list of products.

Each product can be selected or unselected. The user has to choose his products and then hit the continue(submit) button.

To indicate selection I have used http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

My problem is that when the page loads, some products are supposed to be selected by default.

The code I have for this is as follows:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.products}" var="product" varStatus="status">
    <li>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div style="width: 100%;">
                        <div>
                            <div><b>#{product.productName}</b></div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <div class="make-switch switch-mini " data-on-label="Yes" data-off-label="No">
                                <input class="switch#{status.index}" type="checkbox"></input>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" class="checked#{status.index}" value="#{product.initiallySelected}"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ui:repeat>
```

I have javascript that needs to mark the initially selected products as "checked", but nothing I've tried has worked so far. Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    flipSwitches(0);
}

function flipSwitches(index) {
    if ($(".checked"+index).length != 0) {
        var b = $(".checked"+index).val();
        alert(b);
        if (b == "true" || b == true) {
            alert("selected");
            // $(".switch"+index).attr('checked', true);
            // $(".switch"+index).bootstrapSwitch('toggleStatus');
            // $(".switch"+index).bootstrapSwitch('status');
            // $(".switch"+index).bootstrapSwitch('setState', true);
        }

        flipSwitches(index+1);
    }
}
```

I'm using JSF 2.1 (Apache MyFaces 2.1.5), JQuery 2.0.2, with a Java bean in the backend. If anyone can help me out, or perhaps point out what I'm doing wrong, I'd be super!

Answer (score 1):

Add id to the input i.e

```
<input id="myswitch" type="checkbox"/>
```

Then you can make it checked by

```
if(status==true){
    $('#myswitch').prop('checked',true);
}
```

That is how i did and it worked for me.